# database for game in lua connect to a website php

Tags: php, lua

I have a web in php with mysql, and i want make a game in lua for mobile, I need to conect the aplication in lua with the database of my web.

How can i do it?
Thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is the [luasocket library](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/).

If you developed your game using some framework (like Corona SDK) then it's possible that it already has bindings for connecting to remote databases / websites.